# Conditional execution of batch files in TFS release pipeline

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working over the TFS and facing an issue in which there are different folders are available in TFS Repository

Ex:

C#Project
Extreme
CCM

Basically they are different technologies folders and tfs users just only do the check in of corresponding folder.

In Release pipeline i have various batch task which basically executes some batch script file over agent and execute.

There are multiple batch tasks and they perform some actions and my problem is that i want to execute conditionally batch files.

For ex if any changes occur over the C# application it won't execute some of the scripts, if a changes occur over a specific folder then a specific bat file will execute rest won't execute.

Comment: Just trying to understand your question. You have a TFS git repository that contains different folders for different technologies. You want to run certain batch scripts based on where the change happened. is that right?

Comment: Yes that kind of condition i m looking for in tfs 2017 release

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing out-of-the-box that allows you to execute tasks conditionally based on folder where changes were. However, you can do what you want to do it two ways

1) Create a separate build definition for each of your technology areas. Use the Path filter in your trigger to control which build gets triggered based on the path of your changed files.

[image]

2) Create variables for each technology in your build definition. At the start of the build definition, add a Powershell task (or something similar) that sets the appropriate variable(s) based on what files were changed. You can use these variables in the custom condition for your task execution.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response,  further would like to mention i had tried to do 1st approach but due to some   multi client issue i have to drop that idea. For second approach i am trying to achive checkin information from a specific folder so i can be able to set the variables from power shell script but yet not able to get the checkin information. Plz share some code i can be able to achive the second approach

Comment: I won't be able to write the whole code but if you are using git (I assume you are), you can play on the git to get name of files in the latest commit. e.g. 

git show --pretty="" --name-only HEAD

Get the output from above to a variable or file and read lines to get file names

Comment: Sorry i am not using git we are using tfs for repository,  if possible you can share some sample script which can help me to get changes information from folder

Comment: you can do something similar using tf command line tool. Something like 

tf vc status

might be useful.